# How to calculate Precision and Recall If There is No Negative Class

Tags: performance, matrix, precision, metrics, evaluation

I want to evaluate the outputs of an LLM using precision and recall but I only classified for each output is correct or not. Is it possible to calculate precision and recall without negative class?

I tried for inputting FN = 0 and TN = 0. So the recall is 100% and the for this case. But I haven't found any similar case for this from journals or articles.